# Request timeout issue

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, request

I have web application with WCF service. That service contains method that implements message notification. The problem is that with big number of users it takes too much time and throws request timeout exception. What is the best way to solve this problem. Increasing time for request is not available, user won't wait more than minute. Maybe multi-threading or async invocation of notification  method will help? Or is there better solution?

Comment: You will have to figure out what the bottleneck on your server is.

Comment: Method i've said about is invoked from same WCF service and it's void. So one method that runs quick invokes other, that runs much long. I'm looking for way not to wait for finishing of long time method, but continue running of invoker method, and return to main code after it's finished.

Comment: And what are your Instantiation mode an Concurrency mode settings?

Comment: They are set by default. I've tried to set Concurrency mode - Multiple, but it doesn't help. Or I need to set change Instantiation mode or some other settings too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your notification method is not essential for the request to be serviced effectively, then move it to another thread.

As an architectural point you may consider moving all notifications to their own service, the API of which can then be consumed asynchronously.
See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb885132.aspx) for how.